# How to pass sql variable to like condition SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I am creating dynamic sql query and passing variable to like statement 
here is my code

```
 DECLARE @DBname1 VARCHAR(200),@query VARCHAR(200),@tname VARCHAR(200);
  SET @DBname1='core'
  SET @tname = 'abc'
 SET @tname ='''+ '%' + @tname +'''+ '%'
 PRINT @tname 
SET @query= 'Select * FROM '+@DBname1+ '.information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like '+ @tname 
PRINT @DBname1
PRINT @query
EXEC (@query)
```

problem is i m not able to pass single quote to like variable , above code show error message

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator

If I change my code to

```
SET @tname ='%' + @tname + '%'
```

then the single quote is removed from variable and become `TABLE_NAME like %test%` and it does not execute because a single quote is missing.

So I want to know how I can add single quote to sql variable before passing it to like condition or how to concatenate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do like this...

```
DECLARE @DBname1 VARCHAR(200),@query VARCHAR(200),@tname VARCHAR(200);
SET @DBname1='core'
SET @tname = 'abc'
PRINT @tname 
SET @query= 'Select * FROM '+@DBname1+ '.information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like ''%'+ @tname + '%'''
PRINT @DBname1
PRINT @query
EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me , i am searching for this from last 2 days .. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad about that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CONCAT` like this:

```
SET @query= CONCAT('Select * FROM ', 
               @DBname1, 
               '.information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like ', 
               '''%', @tname, '%''')
```